# mdt: skipping task sequence?

Tags: mdt-2010, windows-7

I have imaged a win7 machine and imported it into MDT. I have setup a single task sequence that should be installing the OS. I 'updated' the deployment share and burned the .ISO file to a disc.

I put this disc into a machine, it boot to the setup but never asks me for a task.. in fact it doesn't put up any dialogs at all. It then reboots back to the 'click any key to boot from DVD' text.

Clearly I have something conflicting in my setup .ini files.

```
[bootstrap.ini]
[Settings]
Priority=Default

[Default]
DeployRoot=\\server.edu\CES_DeploymentShare$



[customsettings.ini]
[Settings]
Priority=Default
Properties=MyCustomProperty

[Default]
OSInstall=Y
SkipAppsOnUpgrade=YES
SkipCapture=YES
SkipAdminPassword=YES
SkipProductKey=YES
SkipDomainMembership=YES
SkipTimeZone=YES
SkipFinalSummary=YES

WSUSServer=http://server.edu
```

NOTE: the test system doesn't have a working partition. The disc is unformatted.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW: formatting the drive made this error go away. One should be able to create / format partitions via MDT but I bypassed this work in the interests of staying employed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an Idea (this is what I do):

- Have two entries for disk partitioning; one for the primary disk
  and the other for the secondary (if present).
- Set the secondary disk format to continue on error. Just incase the computer does not have more than one disk.
- Set each one to each disk number E.G. `Primary` disk = disk 0 and the `secondary` = 1
- Set the first entry disk entry to make an extra "active" partition (checkbox)
- Do not set that on the second disk entry because it is unnecessary to have more than one and may cause errors (with booting the computer).
- On the partition configurations configure it to NTFS and the size 100% and set quick format
- Only set the first one to be a boot partition

---

Notes:

- This setup is using a custom task sequence instead of using a standard client task sequence.
- It also uses MDT 2013 and WDS (Server 2012 R2)
- It does not include SCCM
- XML if the task sequence is available if needed :)

Hope this helps! if it does work then see if your boss will keep you after you improve the deployment systems to improve other tasks (or you can keep doing everything manually...)